# Migration from CentOs6.9 to CentOS 7.x

Tags: centos-7, migration, centos-6

I have a server machine running on CentOS 6.9 where more than 200 user accounts exist and DNS service and NIS service are working.

What is the best way to migrate this server to a new machine on CentOS 7.x?